# Não mostrar banner com data de expiração vencida

Tags: php, mysql

Estou tentando mostrar em meu site banner´s que não estejam com data de expiração vencidas, tenho em meu banco um banner com as seguinte datas:

A data atual é: *2015-02-07*

Data de Expiração: *2015-02-08*

O script que fiz está assim:

```php
<?php if ($totalRows_rsBanner > 0) {  ?>
<?php do {
            $imagem = substr($row_rsBanner['imagem'],3);
            $url = $row_rsBanner['url'];

            $DataAtual = date("Y-m-d"); // data atual
            $timestamp_DataAtual = strtotime($DataAtual); // converte para timestamp Unix

            $DataExpiracao = $row_rsBanner['data_expiracao']; // data de expiração do anúncio
            $timestamp_DataExpiracao = strtotime($DataExpiracao); // converte para timestamp Unix

?>
            <?php if ($timestamp_DataAtual > $timestamp_DataExpiracao){ ?>
               <li><a href="<?php echo $url; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $imagem; ?>"></a></li>
            <?php } ?>
            <?php } while ($row_rsBanner = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsBanner)); ?>
<?php } ?>
```

O campo de `data_expiracao` está com o formato `Date`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O seu sinal de comparação estava invertido.

Mais uma dica: use o objeto `\DateTime` para trabalhar com as datas. Assim fica mais fácil comparar datas.

```
<?php

if ($totalRows_rsBanner > 0) {
    do {
        $imagem        = substr($row_rsBanner['imagem'],3);
        $url           = $row_rsBanner['url'];
        $DataAtual     = new \DateTime(); // sem argumentos = data atual
        $DataExpiracao = new \DateTime($row_rsBanner['data_expiracao']); // data de expiração do anúncio
        if ($DataAtual < $DataExpiracao) { ?>
            <li><a href="<?php echo $url; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $imagem; ?>"></a></li>
        <?php }
    } while ($row_rsBanner = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsBanner));
}
```

Comment: Olá @Rodrigo Rigotti, boa noite, muito obrigado pela dica de utilização do objeto, valeu mesmo.